# Go back to previous activity from BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to "go back" programatically from a BroadcastReceiver. Since I cannot call finish() I'm not sure how it can be done

This is my code:

```
public class PhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (telephony.getCallState() == 0) {
            // How can I go to the previous activity from here?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do as below,

```
  public class PhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (telephony.getCallState() == 0) {



   runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
     @Override
          public void run(){
          //to call activity.
          backActivity();
        }
      });
    }
}
}

public void backActivity()
  {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ["your back activity."].class);

    // I've tried multiple different flags to no avail.
      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      startActivity(intent);


    }
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. How would this go to the previous activity? Maybe I'm wrong but "your back activity." seems to suggest this would always start a specific activity instead of going back.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClass(context, YourGoBackActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

You can use intent to jump to the activity you want so that you can "go back" to you activity.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Rico I'd just edited my answer to make it more clear and I think it is the answer of this question.